# Compare all array values with a single string - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

Is there a short way to write this? Like below:

```
<?php

$true=1;
$false=0;

$valid = array (
                "part1" => $true,
                "part2" => $true,
                "part3" => $true
);

if($valid == $true){
echo "All the values are True!";
}else{
echo "At list one of the values is False";
}

?>
```

Instead of this:

```
 <?php

    if($valid['part1'] == $true && $valid['part2'] == $true && $valid['part3'] == $true{
    echo "All the values are True!";
    }else{
    echo "At list one of the values is False";
    }

    ?>
```

I have tried writing it as showed in the first example but it doesn't work

Comment: `if (count(array_filter($valid)) == count($valid)) { echo 'All the values are Truthy'; } else { echo 'at least one of the values is falsey'; }`

Comment: `array_filter` is probably slower than the `array_unique` answer below.

Comment: @mark use `array_unique` and equal it to 1 will make the code much faster and much less code is used in general

Comment: @QuakeCore gave the best answer though must admit i didnt see that approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!in_array($false,$valid){
echo "All the values are True!";
}else{
echo "At list one of the values is False";
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer of yet

Comment: Agreed, best method when you have only two possibilities. +1

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)' second option to search for values matching your variable, and compare the number of results against the total number of elements in your array:

```
if (count(array_keys($valid, $true)) == count($valid)) {
    echo "All the values are True!";
} else {
    echo "At leastone of the values is False";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its an array not a variable you cant just  === it

you will have to use

```
if (count(array_unique($allvalues)) === 1 && end($allvalues) === 'true') {
echo "All the values are True!";
}else{
echo "At list one of tha values is false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with that:

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => true,
    'key2' => true,
    'key3' => true,
);

$status = true;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(!$value) {
        $status = false;
        break;
    }
}
if($status) {
    echo "All the values are True!";
}
else {
    echo "At list one of the values is False";
}
```

Comment: not the best approach given you are skipping out on opportunities to do this way more efficiently.

but this is still another approach to it

Comment: @BuddhiAbeyratne - True. After my post, I have see the others awnsers with in_array() and array_keys() but I like my way to to it. Always good to know how to do it without specials functions.